# How to flop multiple images using imagemagik?

Tags: imagemagick

I tried to flip horizontally the images in a specific folder using ImageMagik. But the `mogrify -flop *jpg` is changing all the images in their mirror images. I want to keep the initial images and for the flopped ones I want to rename them as `*_flop.jpg`. I am stuck: How to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are on Linux or OSX, like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
for f in *.jpg; do
   new="${f%%.jpg}_flop.jpg"
   echo convert "$f" -flop "$new"
done
```

At the moment, it does nothing, it just tells you what it would do. If you like what it shows, just remove the word `echo` and run it again.

Save the code above as `flopper`, and then go to Terminal and type this:

```
chmod +x flopper         # Just do this one time to make the script executable (runnable)
./flopper                # Actually run it
```

Answer (score 1):

**Update:**

For newer versions of ImageMagick (version 7 onwards) you do not need to write:
`convert -flop`

Instead you need to write:

`magick -flop`

So your script essentially becomes:

```
#!/bin/bash/

for file in *.jpg
do 
magick $file -flop ${file%%.jpg}_flop.jpg
done
```

**Note:** This works when your filenames don't have spaces or newlines in them.